# Conditional expectation of an exponential random variable given it is smaller than another independent exponential r.v.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

We have two exponentially distributed random variables,
$X\sim \exp(\theta)$ and $Y\sim \exp(\mu)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent from each other.
What is $E[X|X<Y]$ and $E[X|X>Y]$?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2521301/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $E(X\mid X<Y)$. What you need are $P(X<Y)$ and $E(X1_{X<Y})$. As an example, we consider $E(X1_{X<Y})$, for which we note that
\begin{align*}
E(X1_{X<Y}) &= E\big(E(X1_{X<Y} \mid X) \big)\\
&=E\big(X E(1_{X<Y} \mid X) \big)\\
&=E\left(X\, e^{-\mu X} \right).
\end{align*}
The remaining is now straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the quick answer. Could you please help provide more explanations of your equations (especially the first line)? I am not that good in probabilities thus could not really understand them. I assume $1_{X<Y}$ is the indicator function. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Dong: Yes, $1_{X<Y}$ is an indicator function. The first step is based on the tower law of conditional expectation.