# Conditional expectation of two exponential random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

$X$ and $Y$ are two independent exponential random variables:

$P(X \geq x)=e^{-\lambda_1 x}$ for every $x>0$;

$P(Y \geq y)=e^{-\lambda_2 y}$ for every $y>0$;

How to calculate the expectation of $X$ under the condition that $X<Y$?

i.e. How to calculate $E(X|X<Y)$?

===========================================

I'm also wondering why I am wrong:

$E(X)=E(X|X<Y)*P(X<Y)+E(X|X \geq Y)*P(X \geq Y)$

$E(X)=1/\lambda_1$

$P(X<Y)=\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$

$E(X|X \geq Y)=E(X)+E(Y)=1/\lambda_1+1/\lambda_2$

$P(X \geq Y)=\lambda_2/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$

However, the result of $E(X|X<Y)$ is $0$.

===I see $E(X|X \geq Y)$ should be $E(X)+E(Y|Y<X)$...

Comment: I tried to solve it by calculating $P(X<x | X<Y)=P(X<x, X<Y)/P(X<Y)$. I think I can make Y a constant y first, and then integrate y from 0 to +inf. However, I'm stuck when solving $P(X<x, X<Y)$. Is it similar to $Z=min(X, Y)$? Besides, when integrating y from 0 to +inf., I cannot find a $\lambda_2$ related part. T_T

Comment: I think I can verify the result with $E[X| X< Y] * P(X<Y) + E[Y | X \geq Y] *P(X \geq Y) = E[min(X, Y)]$

Comment: Why not stick to the very definition of the conditional expectation $$E(X\mid X<Y)=\frac{E(X\mathbf 1_{X<Y})}{P(X<Y)}$$ and to the very definition of the expectation in terms of the joint PDF $$E(X\mathbf 1_{X<Y})=\int_\mathbb Rf_Y(y)\int_{-\infty}^yxf_X(x)dxdy\ ?$$ More sophisticated approaches exist, such as starting from $$E(X\mathbf 1_{X<Y}\mid X)=Xe^{-\lambda_2X}$$ but the robust, elementary, one above works.

Comment: Thanks! I got the result: $1/(λ_1+λ_2)$

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to notice that we can express the given event $\{X<Y\}$ equivalently as $\{M=X\}$ where we introduce a new random variable $M=\min(X,Y)$.
Then we can use the fact that the minimum of independent exponentials is independent of their ordering so that we have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[X|X<Y] = \mathrm{E}[X|M=X] = \mathrm{E}[M|M=X] = \mathrm{E}[M] = \frac1{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.
\end{align}

Or from your law of total expectation approach, we have
\begin{align}
\frac1\lambda=\mathrm{E}[X] &= \mathrm{E}[X|X<Y]\cdot \mathrm{P}[X<Y] + \mathrm{E}[X|X>Y]\cdot \mathrm{P}[X>Y]\\
&= \mathrm{E}[X|X<Y]\cdot \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} + \big[\mathrm{E}[X] + \mathrm{E}[Y|Y<X] \big]\cdot\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.
\end{align}
In the above, we used that given that $\{X>Y\}$, then $X=\max(X,Y)$ and $Y=\min(X,Y)$ and $X+Y=\max(X,Y)+\min(X,Y)$ so that
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[X|X>Y] &= \mathrm{E}[X+Y-M|X>Y]\\
&= \mathrm{E}[(X-M) + Y|X>Y]\\
&= \mathrm{E}[(X-M)|X>Y] + \mathrm{E}[Y|Y<X] &(\text{linearity})\\
&= \mathrm{E}[(X-M)|X>M] + \mathrm{E}[Y|Y<X]\\
&= \mathrm{E}[X] + \mathrm{E}[Y|Y<X] &(\text{memoryless})\\
\end{align}